# Seperating two (image) signals in Fourier Space / Denoising

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, noise

i have a problem here which is not so easy to solve. 
I have a measurement system which provides me two signals:

-The "contrast" channel" - this is the main channel on the object

-A second channel which provides me some low-frequency/pseudo-3D information about the object

Specifics are not so important. All i know is that these two signals are correlated in "some way" so i want to use the second channel for denoising my main channel signal.

I transform both images into Fourier-space. How to i continue now? I tried to create a binary mask which filters out the frequencies with the highest absolute values for the secondary channel. 
This did not work out. 
Simply substracting both signals in Fourier-space did not work out as well. Also, i tried to create the masks for imaginary and real parts of the Fourier signal of my second channel. I don't have a high theoretical background about signal separation in Fourier space, so i would like to know how to i find out correlations between two signals, and how can i use this correlation to reduce my noise in the main channel.

I am happy for any literature or further information about how to do this. Thank you!